# (Next.JS) Using the development build locally

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When working on a Next.JS project (hosted on Heroku) I find a few errors like these:

Promise rejected after context unloaded: Actor 'Conduits' destroyed before query 'RuntimeMessage' was resolved

.....

Error: Minified React error error #423; ... #482;

visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423
for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for
full errors and additional helpful warnings.

When visiting the indicated site I see:

We highly recommend using the development build locally
when debugging your app since it tracks additional debug
info and provides helpful warnings about potential problems
in your apps, but if you encounter an exception while using
the production build, this page will reassemble
the original text of the error.

So here is my question.

What am I supposed to do in order to follow the given advice ?
In other words, what is the way to use development build locally ?

Just to make the question a bit more concrete. Below is the very code I am working on.
At this point, I only want the button to toggle the display, but this does not work.

```
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';
import channelsPool from "@/lib/channels";
import React from 'react';
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';


export default async function DB_ChanList() {
  const [listDisplay,setListDisplay] = useState(true);
  const theChannels = await channelsPool()

  const swapDisplay = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setListDisplay(!listDisplay)
  } /* End of swapDisplay */

  
  return <div>
        {listDisplay &&
            theChannels.map(item => (
                <div key={item as string}>
          <button onClick={(e)=>swapDisplay(e)} value={item}>
            <b>{item}</b>
          </button>
                </div>
            ))
        }
        {!listDisplay &&
      <div>THE:unitID::</div>
        }
    </div>
} /* End of DB_ChanList */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async client components, as per Next.js docs [client components cannot be async functions](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-async-client-component).

You may run your application locally with `next dev`, this will run your application in development and provide more details on errors you are getting.

Additionally, you may run `next build` to see potential warnings Next.js gives when building your application.

Comment: @Felix_Yeung. Since this answer gave me some valuable help in moving forward, I willingly accepted it. Unfortunately I am not yet all done with the whole thing. For that reason I created a new post, with an updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768498/mongoose-webpack-imported-module-not-a-function